# How amazon Rekognition handles data privacy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

My question is a little bit general, we want to build a solution based on amazon rekognition. But we want to make sure that amazon don't keep our data after the process is completed for example. When i use the detect_text function in boto3 like this.

```
response = client.detect_text(Image={'Bytes': images_bytes})
```

After i get the response, what happen to the images_bytes that has been uploaded to amazon for processing? Is it automatically destroyed or amazon keeps it locally?

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that AWS would be able to provide you with specific details of how it implements a service.

AWS does have various security certifications that might address your general question of how customer data is handled.

See: [Cloud Compliance - Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/)